# Failed MOSFET in electronic speed controller

Tags: mosfet

MOSFET blow infrequently in a 24 V speed controller/motor combination. The max draw of current reaches no where near the 40 A rating of MOSFET. The voltage has NO spikes we are aware of as been tested with an oscilloscope (very clean). What possibly could take the MOSFET out other than mentioned above. Thanks a lot

Tested with oscilloscope and clamp on ammeter. All within safe ranges.
java

Comment: Welcome! Please show Vgs and Vds oscillograms. Please post a schematic.

Comment: There are always voltage spikes when you interrupt current through an inductance. That's physics. Need much more info detailed info otherwise we would just be randomly throwing out guesses as to all the possible things that could go wrong in a motor controller design.

Comment: For example, insufficient or inappropriate MOSFET switching. Also, current rating numbers in MOSFET datasheets are garbage. They are magical numbers obtained under conditions you can't achieve in the real world. You need to actually calculate your conduction and switching losses and heat dissipation through heatsink or board at the levels you are driving the MOSFET at.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Heat is definitely not a problem.They are not getting very warm

Comment: Do you have a contact number for anybody that can help ?

Comment: I don’t even mind paying for somebody to help who has the expertise

Comment: Just post the schematic.